# create a drop down in laravel 7 with list values from postgres database, and insert in another text field from the same database

Tags: laravel

i am new to laravel 7, i have a postgres database table contact with two columns name and email id. the drop menu values will list the values from the name column, the corresponding value in email id has to displayed in the adjacent text box.

could you guys please help with code, in terms of view and controller.

Thanks

Comment: This is not a Postgres question. Search on 'laravel dropdown' to get a whole list of examples of how to do this.

Comment: Thanks. Updated the tag..